# What could cause occasional continued 404 errors that were originally triggered by high website traffic?

Tags: wordpress, 404, performance, high-traffic

I have a website where one page received huge traffic in one moment, causing errors 404.

Next day, traffic returned to normal but some percent of this page visitors still receive this error (5-10%).

Other pages on the same website are working without any errors.

Website is Wordpress on Amazon server. If it can have any relation, this page is connected with Mautic.

What can I do to resolve this issue, and also, what can I do to avoid mass errors when next peak comes?

Comment: Are you using a content delivery network (CDN)?

Comment: I decided not to, as this is a local website

Comment: "this is a local website" - as in a local _intranet_? So not public facing? And this small percentage of visitors see this 404 consistently for the same page? When other visitors see the page as normal? Sounds like a caching issue of some kind? Do you have proxy servers on your network? (A 404 is a bit of a strange response when the site is under load?)

Comment: Local site, as public site intended for a geographic region. Problem occurs on one page only (the one that had huge traffic in a single day). During this peak, everyone received 404. Now - page works for some visitors while, in the same moment, others receive 404. No proxy.